# Publishing method does not add parameters in the post method

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 5.2 and Swift 5.0

I am doing a publishing method with two parameters since it is a login. It does not add the parameters in the `post` method.

In postman the URL works well; if this same method is in the URL and I add the parameters as a single string, it works, but if I add them as seen in the code below, it does not work.

```
func apiCall(){
  
    let dic: Parameters = [
            "usuario": "user",
            "password": "123456"
       ]
    AF.request(url,method: .post,parameters: dic,
                         encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
               switch response.result {
               case .success(let value):
                   print("VALUE:",value)
                   print(response.request!)
                  print(dic)
               case .failure(let error):
                   print("RESPONSE ERROR：", error)
               }
       }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please, take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) How does the request look like? How it should look like (we don't know)? URL parameters? JSON in the body? Headers? Use some tools (like Proxyman, Charles, ...) to intercept your request to be able to validate it, see how it looks like and if it's valid based on your needs.

Comment: Hello good afternoon in postman the url works well, this same method if in the url I add the parameters as a single string it works, but if I add them as seen in the image it does not work.

Comment: Can you show use the URL which works? Just these parameters (`&...`). Wild guess, but your dictionary, `"usuario": "user"` is correct? Shouldn't it be `"user": "usuario"`?"

Comment: `URLEncoding.default` are you sure about that? Also, quick tip: Alamofire has a debug print as a `curl` request, and Postman can generate `curl` code. What about meeting them halfway and find the difference.

Comment: Well, by curl it cannot send it, I had to modify the API to accept json and thus if it worked